top-alignment of tables in a table
I have two predefined tables and want to stuck them into another table.
How can I have the cell contents top-aligned here?
Is there a way to do this as elementary as possible?

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{B9D5A5}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.8125pt}% seems to be necessary
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}

\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3mm}}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\columncolor{mygreen}}P}

\def\cc{\cellcolor{mygreen}}
\def\x{\footnotesize\textsf{x}}

\def\I{\begin{tabular}{| P | P | Q |}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{L}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{M}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{R}  \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x  \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\def\II{\begin{tabular}{| P |}
\hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{array} [t] { c c c }
\I & \rightarrow & \II
\end{array}

\end{document}


Raise the boxes by -\height.
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{center} % so definitions are local
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{B9D5A5}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.8125pt}% seems to be necessary
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}

\newcolumntype{P}{w{c}{3mm}}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\columncolor{mygreen}}P}

\newcommand\cc{\cellcolor{mygreen}}
\newcommand\x{\footnotesize\textsf{x}}

\newcommand\I{%
  \begin{tabular}{| P | P | Q |}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{L}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{M}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{R}  \\ \hline
  &  & \x \\ \hline
  &  & \x \\ \hline
  &  & \x \\ \hline
  &  & \x \\ \hline
  &  & \x \\ \hline
  &  & \x \\ \hline
  &  & \x \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand\II{%
  \begin{tabular}{| P |}
  \hline
  \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \cc  \\ \hline
  \cc  \\ \hline
  \cc  \\ \hline
  \cc  \\ \hline
  \cc  \\ \hline
  \cc  \\ \hline
  \cc  \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}

\raisebox{-\height}{\begin{tabular}{@{}cc} \I & ${}\rightarrow{}$ \end{tabular}}%
\raisebox{-\height}{\II}

\end{center}

\end{document}

Note the easier definition of the P column type.
You may want to define \x by
\newcommand{\x}{$\scriptstyle\times$}

rather than with \textsf{x}.

If at the end you do
\raisebox{\dimeval{-\height+\baselineskip}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc} \I & ${}\rightarrow{}$ \end{tabular}%
}%
\raisebox{-\height}{\II}

you get the following


Since @cis asked for a solution that is as elementary as possible, here is an alternative. It uses tikz and depending on your point of view it is very elementary: using tikz it is easy to directly align the content of "nodes". Instead of the last array environment that combines the two arrays in an array, just use the following (I only showed the necessary changes):
% your latex header goes here, just add the next two lines:
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    % your definitions of the two tables etc goe here

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (table1) {\I};
        \node (arrow) [right=0cm of table1.east, anchor=west] {$\rightarrow$};
        \node (table2) [right=0.6cm of table1.north east, anchor=north west] {\II};
    \end{tikzpicture}

This also gives you additional ways of positioning objects.
Last but not least, if you decide (e.g. for aesthetic reasons) that you want to align the top lines of the tables this is easily possible as well.

Here is a solution with multirow (to shift the arrow down). The two stacks can be top-adjusted with the [t] option in each tabular. The [t] option in the final array doesn't do anything, because these options specify the alignment with the surrounding text/elements, not the alignment inside the array/tabular.
But because the righthand box starts with a \hline (which will be the alignment point), and the left box doesn't (so the baseline of the text in the first row will be the alignment point), I add a \vskip0pt to the lefthand box, making that the alignment point.
Then I shift the arrow down 5.4 rows with \multirow. The 5.4 is just found experimentally.
The rest I kept the same.
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{B9D5A5}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.8125pt}% seems to be necessary
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}

\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3mm}}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\columncolor{mygreen}}P}

\def\cc{\cellcolor{mygreen}}
\def\x{\footnotesize\textsf{x}}

\def\I{\begin{tabular}[t]{| P | P | Q |}
\noalign{\vskip0pt}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{L}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{M}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{R}  \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x  \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\def\II{\begin{tabular}[t]{| P |}
\hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{array} { c c c }
\I & \multirow[b]{5.4}*{$\rightarrow$} & \II
\end{array}

\end{document}



I hope this works for you.
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{B9D5A5}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.8125pt}% seems to be necessary
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}

\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3mm}}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\columncolor{mygreen}}P}

\def\cc{\cellcolor{mygreen}}
\def\x{\footnotesize\textsf{x}}

\def\I{\begin{tabular}[t]{| P | P | Q |}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{L}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{M}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{R}  \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x  \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
 &  & \x \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\def\II{\begin{tabular}[t]{| P |}
\hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\cc  \\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}


\begin{tabular} [t] { c c c }
\I & \parbox[t][2cm]{10pt}{\vfill $\rightarrow$} & \II
\end{tabular}


\end{document}


